# iPad Air 2 - How to enable device rotation

Tags: ipad

I am working with a new iPad Air 2. I cannot figure out how to change the view to landscape.. There is no side button, and I am tired, but I cannot see a preference in Settings.

Comment: are you on iOS 8.1 ?

Comment: Good thinking. thanks, but yep. 8.1 (12B410)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is apparently an option to adjust screen rotation in the Control Center on the iPad Air 2, since it has no side switch. (Control Center can be accessed by swiping up from he bottom of the screen).

Comment: Thanks Scot. You are right on.. I've added a comment below to state explicitly -- but for the record - as of 8.1, the Control Center has 6 buttons in the center of the panel. Lock/unlock is the last on the right.

Answer (score 0):

The just [released](http://www.forbes.com/sites/amitchowdhry/2014/10/20/apple-ios-8-1-to-launch-today-heres-what-is-coming-in-the-update/) Apple iOS 8.1 fixes the

> Fixes bugs that could cause screen rotation to stop working

among other stuff.

Where is it:

You probably have your switch set to be used for mute instead of rotation lock. Click on the setting and when in that screen select general look in the right hand side panel.  Setting > General. >  USE SWITCH TO:  select the "Lock Rotation" option.

Comment: iPad Air 2 - there is no side switch.

Comment: I didn't vote down, so, I pushed it back up.. I can not find either a switch, or a lock rotation setting. This is my third iPad, so I'm familiar where the settings used to be..

Comment: Don't worry about voters, still thank you, I am just trying to work with you here :) I got my information from here http://appleinsider.com/articles/14/10/16/apples-ipad-air-2-eschews-physical-orientation-lock-switch

Comment: That's it! In the center of the Control Center, there are 6 buttons. The lock is the last button on the right. Thanks for helping, and especially the link to apple insider.